# How to set focus on a particular row in a TDBgrid Delphi

Tags: delphi, gridview

I want to set the  focus on a specific row on a Tdbgridview.
First, I choose the criteria field ( column concerned by search ex: FisrtName) from a combo box then I type criteria in a TeditField (ex : Jack ).
Then the arrow of the Dbgrifd should point on the concerned row.
How should I do?
thanks.

Comment: Use e.g. the [`Locate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Locate) method of the underlying dataset (`DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Locate` if you are sure that your grid has an assigned datasource and dataset; if not, refer directly the dataset instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TDBGrid` component (and all other `TDBxxx` components as well) are what Delphi defines as *dataware* components. This kind of component exists as a visual expression of a dataset.

So, in a `TDBGrid` you should not think about *focusing a row of the grid*, rather think about *positioning a row of the grid's dataset* (using the `Locate` method suggested by TLama, for instance). The grid will notice that the current row of its dataset has changed (because the grid is *aware* about the condition of the dataset) and will focus the corresponding row.

Update 1

Below you can see an example of what I said:

```
MyDataset.Locate('Id', 123, []);
```

The code above simply looks for a certain record in a dataset named `MyDataset`. The first parameter is the name of a existing field in the dataset. So, you have a dataset with some fields and one of those is named `Id`. The second parameter is the value contained in that field in the desired row and the third parameter is some options that do not apply here. Go to the [Delphi docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Locate) for more details on the `Locate` method.

In other words, we are looking for a row in which the field `Id` has the value 123! If the dataset can find such a row, it will become the current record (or row). If there is a `TDBGrid` connected to a `TDataSource` that is connected to `TMyDataset`, it will automatically update to select the corresponding row, just like you wanted.

Comment: I didn't understand very well your response:

Comment: I didn't understand very well your response: I am going to details my components of my app. In fact, my DBgrid is supplied via a Datasource related to a DataSet related to DataProvider and that DataProvider is related a Dataquery (the query is select* from customers).When you talk about changing dataset where should I intervene exactly to get what I want.Thx again

Comment: Some snippet of code will be very appreciated.Sorry to be so demanding

Comment: That's Work so Perfect ! Thanks a lot ALexSC ..You are my savior!